# 'error: cannot find symbol' when declaring a new lunchBag object?

Tags: java, oop, generics, abstract-data-type

error: cannot find symbol when declaring a new LunchBag object in my TestLunchBag class within the main method. There's also a separate class Lunch (with just an int field and constructors/getters/setters).

```
 LunchBag<Lunch> lunchBox = new LunchBag<>();
```

The above declaration gives me an error of "error: cannot find symbol" referring to LunchBag despite LunchBag being defined as a class that implements a GeneralBag interface. Here's the specific error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
LunchBag<Lunch> lunchBox = new LunchBag<>();
  symbol:   class LunchBag
  location: class TestLunchBag
```

The above block is repeated twice for the same line saying there are two errors.

I defined a Lunch class which just has an int field for a code that represents a lunch item (1 for apple, 2 for sandwich etc.). In my class definition of LunchBag

```
   package arraybags;
   import java.util.Arrays;

   public class LunchBag<T> implements GeneralBagInterface<T> {

        private T[] bag;
        private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
        private int numberOfEntries;

        /**
         * Creates an empty bag whose initial capacity is 10.
         */
        public LunchBag() {
            this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
        }

        /**
         * Creates an empty bag having a given initial capacity.
         *
         * @param capacity the integer capacity desired
         */
        public LunchBag(int capacity) {
            numberOfEntries = 0;
            bag = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
        }}
```

My TestLunchBag class' main method and the line where the error shows up is as written above:

```
LunchBag<Lunch> lunchBox = new LunchBag<>();
```

TestLunchBag class code:

```
package arraybags;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class TestLunchBag{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            LunchBag<Lunch> lunchBox = new LunchBag<>();

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = in.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter lunch item (ID):");
            int userLunchItemEntry = in.nextInt();
            Lunch lunch = new Lunch(userLunchItemEntry);

            if (lunch.isValidValue == true)
               {
                  lunchBox.add(lunch);
               }
}}
```

File directory wise: I have a package called arraybags which has:

```
GeneralBagInterface.java
Lunch.java
LunchBag.java
TestLunchBag.java
```

my interface's import and def statement:

```
package arraybags;

public interface GeneralBagInterface <T>{

//general bag operation methods that I override in my LunchBag class
}
```

Just if needed, Lunch class' definition dec and the packages:

```
package arraybags;
public class Lunch {
private int lunchItem;
public boolean isValid = false;

//and relevant methods
}
```

Am I declaring something wrong or could my default constructor not be valid/properly written? If so, how would I properly declare a new LunchBag object that takes in Lunch objects into it's bag array field?

Comment: Could you please post the minimal and complete implementation of the `testLunchBag` class to see problem?

Comment: How do you compile your classes? Why don't you put your classes in a package, as they should, and respect the Java naming conventions?

Comment: The classes are in a package, I just pasted the class definitions. What do you mean by naming conventions specifically?

Comment: @SergeyBrunov done

Comment: Classes start with an uppercase letter. You didn't answer my question: how do you compile your classes. If they are in a package, which ones. Do you import LunchBag inside testLunchBag. Post **all** the relevant code (package and import statements in both classes), and answer my question.

Comment: @JBNizet done and totally missed the capital. Thanks for the catch. Not sure what you mean by compile, I just press run on my netbeans IDE. I know I sound downright ignorant but that's the extent of what I know about my project compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Is `LunchBag` compiled and has it been imported into your `testLunchBag` class (if in case they aren't under same package).

Comment: oh they're under the same package, I posted more info in the edit

Answer (score 0):

Your `LunchBag` class definition seems to be missing a closing "}".